# cPanel displaying inconsistent data

Tags: apache-http-server, cpanel

My cPanel account is acting very weird lately. I made additions an addon domain yesterday and successfully transfer some files and it is working. Also, I have noticed yesterday that my cPanel disk space usage is 100% full. So, I backed-up and deleted some unnecessary files from the server.

Disc Space Usage is:

> 20164.48 / 15000 MB - before

after

> 14243.86 / 15000 MB - after deleting some file.

The weird thing is I didn't delete that amount (size) of files, so I wonder where the discrepancy is.

> 20164.48 - 14243.86?

Then, as I checked today the domain acount I created yesterday was gone. It doesn't exist and the Disc Space Usage is back to 20164.48 :(

Comment: If the domain is gone, and the disk space is back to where it was the previous day, then I would suspect your account was restored overnight.  With cpanel, disk space calculation are carried out overnight as well.  How much did you delete?  Where are you viewing the usage states, on the sidebar or the Disk Usage area?

Comment: yes, I'm viewing it on the sidebar

Comment: Look in the Files / Disk Usage section to get a better understanding where the space is going - it should give you a clearer picture.  Note that this does not include databases.

Comment: It displays same data. I only delete almost 5mb of data yesterday.

Comment: Then the most likely scenario is that the 14GB reading was incorrect.